# How to target different themes / layouts in Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, css, cordova

I'm new to Phonegap and was wondering if it's possible to target different themes / layouts using CSS based on the device OS? i.e. one layout & theme specific to Android, another specific to iOS, another to Windows, etc.

Obviously I would like to keep the UI/UX as close to the native experience as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to add a class to the body for device specific styles by using

```
document.body.className += (" " + window.device.platform);
```

In your CSS, you can then target specific devices, e.g.

```
.iOS #navbar { background-color: #000; }
```

You can find out the device names that Phonegap detects from the [API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.platform)

```
// Depending on the device, a few examples are:
//   - "Android"
//   - "BlackBerry"
//   - "iOS"
//   - "webOS"
```

Comment: Additionally you can use the `.toLowerCase();` method to get rid of the capital